# IdentityServer4 loses logon session

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4

I put IdentityServer4 on azure and it worked correctly, but when I log in to IdentityServer4, it only stays logged in for about 20 minutes and then asks for the login again (redirects to the login screen).

Does anyone know how to log in only once?

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(op => op.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttributeFilter()));

        var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(option =>
            {
                option.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                option.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                option.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                option.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                option.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;

            })
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
            .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        db => db.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            })
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                    builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        db => db.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
            });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddAuthentication("MyCookie")
            .AddCookie("MyCookie", options =>
            {
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
            });


    }
```

Comment: You need to check IS4 logs to figure out why your authentication session was dropped.

Comment: @AlexBuyny Ok, I'll configure Serilog to check what happened. tks

Answer (score 0):

It's not magic and it's just using a cookie. The most likely thing is the lifetime of your authentication cookie. I wouldn't be surprised if it defaulted to 20 minutes.

Comment: I set up all the timeouts for 30 days, but I still did not succeed

Comment: What’s the expiry on the auth cookie?